# The dual space of $C(Y,\mathbb R)$ when $Y$ is a complete and separable metric space

Tags: measure-theory, dual-spaces

Just to be confirmed what is the dual space of $C(Y,\mathbb R)$ i.e the vector space of all continuous functions $f: Y\to \mathbb R$ when $Y$ is complete and separable metric space? Is it the same when $Y$ is compact, which is the space of all signed/complex measures on $Y$? Thanks for any comment.

Even, I would be interested to know the dual space, when continuous functions are bounded or maybe even Lipschitz.

Comment: What exactly is the space $C(Y,\mathbb R)$? What is the topology you put on it?

Comment: For $Y$ not compact, you may need to allow certain finitely-additive measures.  Alternatively, it could happen that there is a countably additive probability measure, and an  element of $C(Y,\mathbb R)$ that is not integrable.

Comment: I would be interested in putting any topology to make the dual space as space of complex/ signed measures on it. But, I do not know much about what difference it may make to put a different topology on it. It would be a really great help for me to know any details about it. Thanks!

Comment: The definition of  a dual space depends on the topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also interested in the space $C_b(Y, \mathbb{R})$ of **bounded** continuous functions endowed with the **topology of uniform convergence**, which is normed by
\begin{equation*}
||f|| := \sup_{y \in Y} |f(y)|, \quad f \in C_b(Y, \mathbb{R}),
\end{equation*}
then the assumption that $Y$ is complete separable metric space is not sufficient for identifying the dual $C(Y,\mathbb{R})'$ with the family of finite Borel measures on $Y$.

Here is a standard counterexample. Let $Y := \mathbb{N}$ and give it the discrete metric; on the other hand, let $C_0(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ be the subspace of $C_b(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$ consisting of convergent sequence. Define a linear functional $L$ on $C_0(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
L(f) := \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n), \quad f \in C_0(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}).
\end{equation*}
It is easy to see that $L$ is bounded and hence continuous. By virtue of the Hahn-Banach theorem, $L$ can be continuously extended over $C_b(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$. However, $L$ cannot be identified with any countably additive measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Two great references to consult...

*Gillman, Leonard; Jerison, Meyer*, Rings of continuous functions., Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 978-0-486-81688-3). ix, 300 p. (2017). [ZBL1380.46022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1380.46022).

*Varadarajan, V. S.*
Measures on topological spaces. (Russian) 
*Mat. Sb.* (N.S.) **55** (97) 1961, 35–100.
English translation: American Mathematical Society Translations, Ser. 2, vol.48 (1965)
[beware: an error in the appendix]